# Можно ли на "StackOverflow на русском" просить обзоры (review) своего кода расположенного на GitHub?

Tags: обсуждение, инспекция-кода

Я хотел бы, в идеале, просить на каждый "Pull Request" своего проекта на GitHub обзор кода, создавая для каждого вопрос.
Например: "Сделайте обзор моего кода `такого то проекта` от `такого то числа`",
и приложить краткое описание и ссылку.
Тут можно так?

Comment: @Димка, дело не в open source. Дело в том, что у Stack Overflow своя специфика, и ваша ситуация не совсем вписывается в эту специфику. Тем не менее, вопрос интересный и я соглашусь с предыдущим комментатором, что стоит задать его на Мете.

Comment: @VladSpirin, не знал о нём, задам вопрос там, спасибо.

Comment: Я уже несколько раз делал ревью кода на гитхабе. Не понимаю возмущение поборников чистоты ruSO, впрочем на вкус и цвет...

Comment: *на каждый "Pull Request" своего проекта на GitHub обзор кода, создавая для каждого вопрос* -- по-моему, это несножко перебор.

Comment: По моему я всё таки указал "в идеале", и имел ввиду что их будет много. Я не могу найти ресурс где можно запрашивать обзор кода написанного преимущественно на русском языке

Comment: @Димка ваш вопрос демонстрирует что многие участники не знакомы с меткой инспекция-кода (филиал codereview.SE на ru.SO) и какого рода вопросы в ней допускаются и какие ответы ожидаются (если *рабочий* код приведён прямо в вопросе, если словами грамотно описано что код делает, если готовы любой отклик о коде получить, и если понимаете что не все участники прочтут описание инспекция-кода метки, то публикуйте вопрос с этой меткой) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SO позиционирует себя как базу знаний. Вопросы с инспекцией кода возможны, но если они локализованы.

К примеру, вы приводите код какого-то алгоритма, у которого есть проблема с производительностью. Или же вы просите совета о том, как улучшит код в соответствии с общепринятым шаблонами.

Если же вы просите проинспектировать ВЕСЬ проект, причём на стороннем ресурсе, то сообществу это никакой пользы не принесёт.

Answer (score 2):

На русском stack overflow, нужно соблюдать условие постановки/решения конкретной задачи, описания возникшей у вас определенной проблемы. Тогда ваша просьба - проинспектировать код может быть услышана. И действительно, "портянки кода" здесь вряд ли воспримут "на ура", все же немного другая специфика.

На Stackexchange есть специальный раздел [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), правда он на английском. Но это может быть даже плюсом.

Еще есть интересный раздел для практики [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Вопрос не в том как воспримут, а можно ли так делать, я уже понял что нельзя. Дело в том что с человеческой точки зрения, нет разницы размещу я здесь 1000 строк кода (мне не сложно), или ссылку (разница только в удобстве), но с точки зрения правил, они запрещают внешние ссылки. Мой код преимущественно на русском, по этому английские ресурсы не подойдут.