# Отсутствие даты и счетчика голосов для комментариев

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Сегодня периодически возникают две проблемы в комментариях:

1. Нет даты комментария.
2. Не обновляется показатель количества проголосовавших За комментарий.

Примеры.

На ruSO ([Дебаг linux kernel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778705)):

> [image]

На Мете ([Можно ли на "StackOverflow на русском" просить обзоры (review) своего кода расположенного на GitHub?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6829)):

> [image]

Comment: Chromium 60.0.3112.113 x32 под  Windows 10 rev.1709, всё отображается корректно.

Comment: [дубликат](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306461/339911)?

Comment: @alexolut похоже на то, в части отображения времени комментариев по крайней мере.